# Показать плавно текст на слайдере через определенное время

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую на сайте слайдер **[fotorama](http://fotorama.io/)**.

Помогите разобраться, что я делаю не так.
Мне нужно при каждом активном слайде показать плавно текст, например, - первый через 1,5 секунды, а второй через 2 секунды. Изначально текст скрыт.

[Вот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/77sh4wqc/3/).

`if($('.fotorama__stage__frame').hasClass('fotorama__active')){ 
    $(this).children('#kkk').delay(1500).show(1000);
    $(this).children('#kkk2').delay(2000).show(1000);
}`

Если у Вас есть предложения, как сделать по другому, буду рад рассмотреть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery считаю использовать нет необходимости в Вашем случае.
У fotorama к активному слайду добавляется `class="fotorama__active"`, а к не активному `class="fotorama__fade-front"`.

Если говорить простым языком, когда слайд еще не активен, у `div`  в котором лежит Ваша картинка, установлен класс `fotorama__fade-front`, после того, как наступило время показа кого-то слайда, класс `fotorama__fade-front` удаляется и вместо него добавляется `fotorama__active`. Исходя их этого, Вы можете воспользоваться этим случаем.

Насколько помню в документации указано, для того, чтобы добавить текст, необходимо написать следующее:

```
<div data-img="images/75bdec4a063c.jpg"><p class="zoom-fotorama">Текст</p></div>
```

Добавляете к тегу `<p>` класс, например, `zoom-fotorama`.
Далее возьму пример стилей из [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/):

```
@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes zoomOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Далее прописываем следующие правила для текста:

```
p.zoom-fotorama{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Это позволит нам в дальнейшем показать текст плавно, так как, если текст будет по-умолчанию виден, то он сначала покажется, а только потом на него сработает далее описанные стили, что очень не красиво. Стили:

```
.fotorama__active .fotorama__html p.zoom-fotorama {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: zoomIn;  
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;                    
}
```

Теперь опишем стили для текста в момент переключения слайда на следующий:

```
.fotorama__fade-front .fotorama__html p.zoom-fotorama {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: zoomOut;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;                  
}
```

Теперь Ваш текст при активном слайде будет плавно появляться и плавно исчезать при переключении слайда на следующий.

Я показал лишь пример реализации для плавного появления и плавного исчезновения текста. Вы можете, конечно, всё сделать под себя индивидуально:)

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!:)